# Why are numpy fractional exponents not working?

Tags: numpy

I have 2 equivalent equations. One is expressed using numpy.sqrt the other is expressed using the power of (-1/2). I get two different answers. Why?

```
print 'var.shape', cache['var'].shape
print 'var: ', cache['var']
print 'eps: ', cache['eps']
print 'nonexponent', (1/np.sqrt(cache['var'] + cache['eps']))
print 'exponent: ', ((cache['var'] + cache['eps']) ** (-1/2))
```

Result

```
>> var.shape (5,)
>> var:  [ 11.67073838  21.89655316  17.16595863   6.65632423   8.94247188]
>> eps:  1e-05
>> nonexponent [ 0.29271882  0.21370369  0.2413603   0.38759881  0.33440362]
>> exponent:  [ 0.08568431  0.04566927  0.0582548   0.15023284  0.11182578]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're on Python 2, where `-1/2` is integer division and produces `-1`.